# Mysql updating table where related table=

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have read a few answers and question, but cannot get the correct syntax
the script I want is to update a status message depending on whether the date is today or in the future
Tables: job and inst
Join JID int(11)
column to be updated  job.ss2  where inst.Install Date condition

here it is

```
   $sql = "UPDATE job LEFT JOIN inst ON job.JID = inst.JID SET ss2 = 
   'INSTBOOKED'  WHERE inst.install Date >= CURDATE()";
```

Comment: Means You have query about update query runnning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include `job.` for `ss2`.
If the `inst.install` field is a `DateTime` field you could do this. Else you might need to reformat the field while comparing.

```
 $sql = "UPDATE job LEFT JOIN inst ON job.JID = inst.JID SET job.ss2 = 
'INSTBOOKED' WHERE `inst`.`install Date` >= CURDATE()";
```

If the name is `install Date`, you can try with backticks in the query as I edited above. You should avoid using spaces in column names, just use underscores ( _ ) instead. (I don't even know if it is possible in MySQL)

Comment: the column is actually inst.`install Date`, so should I  state it
inst.`install Date` or inst.install Date  or inst.Install_Date

Comment: I never do that, `Date` or `DateTime` and even `Timestamp` would be okay to use in date comparison.

Comment: Ah, `Date` is part of the column name? You shouldn't have spaces in column names...